# What is the difference 「光景」「情景」and 「場面」？

Tags: nuances

I know that these terms translate roughly to scene, spectacle, or scenery. What's the difference among them?

Answer (score 3):

**場面** is a neutral, matter-of-factly noun meaning "scene" or "situation". It's widely used in technical or businesslike contexts (video authoring, criminal investigations, level design of games, ...).

> - このゲームは場面を切り替えるたびに長いローディング時間がかかる。
> - 場面に応じて適切な敬語を使えるようにしましょう。
> - 今日は主人公がオフィスで仕事をしている場面を撮影する。

**光景** is a relatively literary word that refers to a "scene" or "scenery" perceived by eyes (光 = light). It can be good or bad, but it's usually special and memorable (e.g., beautiful scenery, murder scene, fierce battle...).

> - 山を登り切ると、目の前に素晴らしい光景が広がっていた。
> - ある戦争映画で見た凄惨な光景が忘れられない。

**情景** refers to a (usually good) "scene" or "vision" vividly imagined in one's mind, or a beautiful scenery that touches one's mind. It's even more literary than 光景. (情 = emotion, feeling)

> - 心に天国の情景を思い浮かべる。
> - この絵画には作者の少年時代の情景が描かれている。
> - のどかな農村の情景