# Difference between 光景, 風景, 景色, 情景, 景観, 眺め, 見晴らし and 場面

Tags: nuances

I am aware that there is a [similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82309/what-is-the-difference-%e5%85%89%e6%99%af-%e6%83%85%e6%99%af-and-%e5%a0%b4%e9%9d%a2) with a great answer, however I feel like it could be expanded upon. I don't have enough points to comment, so I decided to post it as a seperate question.

My question is what's the difference between:

**光景**, **情景**, **景色** **景観**, **眺め**, **見晴らし**, **場面**

I know they all essentially mean view, scenery and/or spectacle, but what are the more nuanced differences?

Also, since **光景**, **情景** and **場面** have been explained in the other question, feel free to leave the definitions out; if you feel like they've been explained well enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **場面**: scene in the sense of "situation"
- **光景**: a memorable scene seen by one's eyes
- **情景**: scene in the sense of "vision", something imagined in one's mind
- **景色**: wide scenery/landscape (typically of nature)
- **風景**: a pleasant, physical sight, not necessarily of nature (though it can be).
- **景観**: beautiful landscape (e.g., of a city) maintained by people
- **眺め**: scenery/scene seen from a distance (眺める = to see from a distance); outlook
- **見晴らし**: wideness/openness/clearness of a view

光景 can refer to any memorable scene/scenery perceived by your eyes. 景色 tends to refer to a *wide* scenery seen from a distance. 景観 tends to be used in the context of city design, etc.

- あの日部屋で見た光景
  the scene I saw in my room that day
- 富士山の山頂から見た景色
  the scenery seen from the top of Mt. Fuji
- 美しい京都の景観を守れ！
  Protect the beautiful landscape of Kyoto!

眺め and 見晴らし are often interchangeable, too, but 眺め focuses on what you're seeing (from a distance), whereas 見晴らし focuses on how far or how much you can see. For example 良い眺め tends to refer to a beautiful/pleasing view, whereas 良い見晴らし tends to refer to an open/clear view.

Still, the following five phrases mean almost the same thing, "wonderful scenery seen from the observation deck of Tokyo Skytree":

- スカイツリーの展望台から見た素晴らしい光景
- スカイツリーの展望台から見た素晴らしい景色
- スカイツリーの展望台から見た素晴らしい景観
- スカイツリーの展望台から見た素晴らしい眺め
- スカイツリーの展望台からの素晴らしい見晴らし

Comment: I feel like 風景 should be included here too.

Comment: I just suggested an edit which includes 風景